# possible to change To: field in email header?

Tags: security, email, sendmail, phishing

I found a phishing email in my inbox that has my email address in the From: field, and an unknown email address in the To: field. It was made like I had sent the email to the unknown email address.

I'd like to ask if it is possible to change the To: field in the email header?
(I know it's possible to change the From: field in email)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your email address was probably in the Bcc field.

> If you don't see your email address in
>   the To: or Cc: fields of the header,
>   the sender has probably mailed you a
>   'blind carbon copy,' or Bcc:. The Bcc:
>   field isn't displayed in the header of
>   received messages. This means that you
>   won't see your email address at the
>   top of any message you receive as a
>   blind carbon copy.

Quoted from [Receiving someone else's mail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10313)

Comment: Actually, there's no need for the spammer to put the address in any header at all.  The SMTP envelope (RCPT TO:) controls who the message is sent to, but it's used only during transport and is discarded once the message is delivered to the recipient.  The To, Cc, and Bcc headers *usually* contain the same addressees, but there's no requirement that they do so.  It's the difference between RFC 5321 [transport] and RFC 5322 [payload] (the current versions of RFC 821 and 822).

Comment: @dkarp, you should make your comment an answer, because it's the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn’t possible to use the To: header field to send an email to an address that isn’t in the To: header field, if the email is sent via SMTP.

Spammers very often use the Bcc: (blind carbon copy) header field to send email to an address that doesn’t appear in the To: header field or the Cc: header field. That is probably what has happened in this case. Your email address is probably in the Bcc: header field. The contents of the Bcc: header field is not shown by your email client.